# Testing Reactjs without node?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, backbone.js, reactjs

I'm building my app using backbone and react inside of a rails app. I saw that all the recommended test packages (jest, jasmine, etc) are all node based. From what I know, I can get node on my rails project but I'd prefer not to.

Is there a way to test with something like jest without node? Or is there another package that isn't based on node that works with react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many test frameworks have browser based test runners, if you're willing to give up command line based testing then you can do this.  Jasmine and Mocha both allow this.

Node.js is the de facto platform for web development tools (Ruby being the second most popular).  Consider adopting the dependency, or you'll be fighting an uphill battle.

Comment: Great thanks. I was slowly coming to that conclusion, but didn't want to accept it.

Comment: It took me a while to accept ruby as a dependency, but I have a few tools that require it.  I understand :-)